# how to generate an camera app in cordova using Visual studio 15

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am just starting to use cordova in Visual studio 15 in my windows 8 system. I want a basic app which has a button "Take Photo" and it should do so when I run my app in any device, whether andriod, ios or windows phone and finaly store the image in some location. I was reading the cordova docs about it and got fully confused. I also want to know whether the look and feel of the app will change when I  install the apps into various devices.

Please help!

Comment: You can use  [cordova-plugin-camera](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html) to take pictures and if you want to do something like copy the image to another location, [cordova-plugin-file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html) is necessary. I don't think the app will have the same feel on different device. because this app will start native photo-taking app, which is different on different devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) plugin (as mentioned in the comments) to take a picture. When you use that plugin you can also specify a `DestinationType` of `FILE_URI` or `NATIVE_URI` and it will save the picture to disk.

As for your question about look and feel: Cordova itself doesn't do anything to provide you a user interface that adapts its UI, but you can use a framework like [OnsenUI](https://onsen.io/) or [Ionic](http://www.ionicframework.com) to do this.

To experiment with Ionic, and the Camera plugin, try [a tutorial](https://github.com/jmatthiesen/cordova-presentations/blob/main/hands-on-labs/Using%20Visual%20Studio%20Tools%20for%20Apache%20Cordova%20to%20build%20apps%20for%20iOS%20and%20Android.docx) I wrote awhile back, which walks you through both of these.